# Update date in column sql

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a date in a table I need to update each month (also need the year to change as well). It is formatted `May2015` for example. Is there a way you can update it automatically with an update statement? Usually this isn't hard, but since the month and year are not split up I am having difficulty.

Thanks.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: This is why you shouldn't store dates as `VARCHAR`

Comment: As @Siyual said every RDBMS has some type of support for native Date or DateTime types. Use those, they are there for a reason. Otherwise what is the point of even having a type system if everything is persisted as a string?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can't change your table, you can make each of your dates the first of each month so you'll have it in `DATETIME` format. Here is an example how:

[Click for DEMO](http://rextester.com/YQSHR90635)

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tempTable') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #tempTable
create table #tempTable(
    vDate varchar(50)
)
insert into #tempTable (vDate) values
('May2015'),
('March2016'),
('August2014')

select
    cast( 
    case 
        when left(vDate,len(vDate) - 4) = 'January' then '01'
        when left(vDate,len(vDate) - 4) = 'February' then '02'
        when left(vDate,len(vDate) - 4) = 'March' then '03'
        when left(vDate,len(vDate) - 4) = 'April' then '04'
        when left(vDate,len(vDate) - 4) = 'May' then '05'
        when left(vDate,len(vDate) - 4) = 'June' then '06'
        when left(vDate,len(vDate) - 4) = 'July' then '07'
        when left(vDate,len(vDate) - 4) = 'August' then '08'
        when left(vDate,len(vDate) - 4) = 'September' then '09'
        when left(vDate,len(vDate) - 4) = 'October' then '10'
        when left(vDate,len(vDate) - 4) = 'November' then '11'
        when left(vDate,len(vDate) - 4) = 'December' then '12'
    end + '/01/' + right(vDate,4) as date)
from 
    #tempTable
```

Then you can use this same logic to update what ever you need.

Answer (score 0):

this is an old Access DB that I am attaching to then trying to use the currentdate function to adjust the string.  I know I want to use UPDATE "fieldname" but it has to remain with the month spelled out.  Know this isnt best practice by far but it is what I got handed.

Comment: Add this as a comment to your question, not as an answer. That way the other folks will see the notification. I also tagged your question with access since you said it's your database. Hopefully someone can help!

Answer (score -1):

If it's not too late, you should change your schema to use DATE or DATETIME instead of a string. If it is too late, you should write a migration that queries each row of your DB, uses a date parsing library to parse it into a DATE or DATETIME, and updates a new column for that row that is DATE or DATETIME.